# IndexOutOfIndexException when running Geek Serendipity Android app download

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-maps-android-api-2, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-messaging

I deployed Google's Mobile Backend starter following the guide at:
https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend

I tested it with the client on those steps, and it runs fine.

Now, I downloaded the client from

https://github.com/bradabrams/GeekSerendipity-io13

and followed the steps at

http://bradabrams.com/2013/05/google-io-2013-session-overview-from-nothing-to-nirvana-in-minutes-cloud-backend-for-your-android-application-building-geek-serendipity/

till Step 3. So far, I can see a map, that has got my location on the map correctly. However, when I look at the AppEngine logs, I see the following exception:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: cause={0} java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at com.google.cloud.backend.beans.FilterDto.getOperand(FilterDto.java:131)
    at com.google.cloud.backend.beans.FilterDto.getDatastoreFilter(FilterDto.java:99)
    at com.google.cloud.backend.spi.QueryOperations.executeQuery(QueryOperations.java:109)
    at com.google.cloud.backend.spi.QueryOperations.list(QueryOperations.java:84)
    at com.google.cloud.backend.spi.EndpointV1.list(EndpointV1.java:227)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:339)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:163)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:121)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Why am I getting this exception?

Things that I have checked:

1. The Project ID and Project Number in Consts.java are correct.
2. I've checked Android Manifest to see that my Maps API Key is correct
3. Package name specified for Maps API Key in Code console is correct: 
   ;com.turbomanage.sample.geekwatch
4. The Appengine backend is running alright by itself. Here is the API explorer link:

   http://forward-alchemy-355.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer
5. The authentication is set to "OPEN" so it shouldn't be getting blocked for any reason.
6. Since I've tested the backend against the Android sample app mentioned at https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/.
   It looks like the backend is running fine.
   Most likely, this looks like a case of the Geek Serendipity client passing wrong parameters.
7. In Eclipse, I inspected the code to see how the CloudQuery and QueryDto looked, and here's how it looks:

CloudQuery:

```
CloudQuery (Geek/PAST): filter: F: op: EQ, values: [name, null]
```

QueryDto:

```
{filterDto={operator=EQ, values=[name, null]}, kindName=Geek, limit=1, regId=APA91bHtELzN0oF2ZtUa91epD7gzxtM8R7EUP7O7w_9ebCxT7bEFbWO9CEhmkulOayXkJ8zRz1eXehfh-ZD4Mru0bug7nbnolrDdzOlbN5orsixKUyyZtMyHOy7MHNfA46gFQEWfvo9FQdCe8fsZ1qlumuyybSgQJw, scope=PAST, sortAscending=false, sortedPropertyName=name}
```

I suspect the problem here is values:[name, null]. But I can't decipher any farther. What should this query really look like?

Based on the app description, we are probably trying to query all available "Geek" instances here, to display on map, but since I don't know this sample code provided by Google intimately, I'm not sure if that's the case. (I'm also new to EndPoints, which is why I'm trying the Geek Serendipity app as a starter)

Also, at this point, our datastore has 0 instances of "Geek" kind so far.

I would really appreciate any pointers that would help me move forward in debugging this.

**Update:**
I tried the same query from the API explorer. It returns an HTTP 200 OK, but I still see the exception on the AppEngine logs.

https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https%3A%2F%2Fforward-alchemy-355.appspot.com%2F_ah%2Fapi#p/mobilebackend/v1/mobilebackend.endpointV1.list?_h=2&resource=%257B%250A++%2522filterDto%2522%253A+%250A++%257B%250A++++%2522operator%2522%253A+%2522EQ%2522%252C%250A++++%2522values%2522%253A+%250A++++%255B%2522name%2522%252C%2522null%2522%250A++++%255D%250A++%257D%252C%250A++%2522kindName%2522%253A+%2522Geek%2522%252C%250A++%2522regId%2522%253A+%2522APA91bHtELzN0oF2ZtUa91epD7gzxtM8R7EUP7O7w_9ebCxT7bEFbWO9CEhmkulOayXkJ8zRz1eXehfh-ZD4Mru0bug7nbnolrDdzOlbN5orsixKUyyZtMyHOy7MHNfA46gFQEWfvo9FQdCe8fsZ1qlumuyybSgQJw%2522%252C%250A++%2522scope%2522%253A+%2522PAST%2522%252C%250A++%2522sortAscending%2522%253A+false%252C%250A++%2522sortedPropertyName%2522%253A+%2522name%2522%250A%257D&

In fact, the error in the logs shows up even if I remove {filterDto={operator=EQ, values=[name, null]} from the query.

I'm starting to wonder if this is an innocuous bug that I'm unnecessarily worrying about. I'm going to continue with the remaining steps and see if I run into any other trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the source code of the Geek Serendipity Android Client code, don't stop at every step to check if the App works.

IT WON'T WORK TILL YOU FINISH SETTING UP AUTHENTICATION! That's how it's designed. It's the final product.

**More explanation follows:**

In the error above, I mentioned the following in the JSON query:

```
operator=EQ, values=[name, null]
```

Here's the code generating this query:

```
getCloudBackend().listByProperty("Geek", "name", Op.EQ,
                                        accountName, null, 1, Scope.PAST,
                                        new CloudCallbackHandler<List<CloudEntity>>() {...
```

In other words, it should have translated to something like:

```
operator=EQ, values=[name, "somefunkyuser@gmail.com"]
```

However, it didn't because I hadn't setup authentication at this point. In other words, in Consts.java, "IS_AUTH_ENABLED" should be "true", and you should also generate and add the "Web Client ID" key there, exactly as specified on http://bradabrams.com/2013/05/google-io-2013-session-overview-from-nothing-to-nirvana-in-minutes-cloud-backend-for-your-android-application-building-geek-serendipity/

Just keep going till the end of the page, following instructions. Once you get to the end of the page, if you've followed correctly, then test out the app, and it'll work.

**Additional Note:**

When generating "CLIENT ID" for an Android Application, make sure you "Register App" twice in the cloud console:

1. For the first one, choose Platform "Android". This will need your package name.
2. For the second one, choose Platform "Web". This will give you a Web Client ID, but you need it for your Android App too. (The Consts.java file needs your "Web Client ID", not your "Android Client ID". Your MBS Authentication page, on the other hand, needs both your Android Client ID as well as your Web Client ID to successfully authenticate with your Android app)